# Linear Interpolation with known values (not filling Nan)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have some GPS data that I am trying to clean and interpolate some columns. I have a Seconds column (derived from GPS that is not clean), Velocity column and a new, clean Time column. I want to create a VelInt column that has Velocity corresponding to the new Time column. I have posted a snapshot.

```
Timestamp   Seconds Velocity    Acceleration    Odometer    Latitude    Longitude   Heart Rate  Player Load Time
81775   04/08/2019 15:17    8177.54 3.95    -0.450055   12749.89    -37.539804  143.847791  0   1167.5  8177.5
81776   04/08/2019 15:17    8177.64 4.05    -0.085043   12750.44    -37.539800  143.847793  0   1167.5  8177.6
81777   04/08/2019 15:17    8177.74 4.07    -0.033785   12750.89    -37.539796  143.847796  0   1167.6  8177.7
81778   04/08/2019 15:17    8177.84 4.04    -0.097840   12751.32    -37.539793  143.847798  0   1167.6  8177.8
81779   04/08/2019 15:17    8177.94 3.97    -0.235883   12751.78    -37.539789  143.847800  0   1167.6  8177.9
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer if you review the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your question.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`). Please read [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That better?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved it with the following

```
x = df_new4['Seconds']
xp = df_new4['Time']
fp = df_new4['Velocity']
df_new4['VelInt']=np.interp(x, xp, fp)
```